# React.JS onChange event not working with using unity-webgl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, onchange, unity-webgl

```
import {Unity} from 'react-unity-webgl';

...

handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
}

render() {
    <div>
 ...
        <div>
            <Unity src="WebGL.json" />
        </div>
 ...
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </div>
 ...
  </div>
}
```

Here onChange(Input) event was working well but after Unity integration it does not work at all. I tried with other input components but same result.

Comment: Is `handleChange` is bound to `this` ? show how you declare your component and how u bind it ?

Comment: Yes, the handleChange is bound to this.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: No. there is nothing any error in console.

Comment: What isn't working? Does nothing log? Are you using es6?

Comment: I am using es6, there is nothing any log for this issue. But the onChange event isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by myself and I posted the answer via below links.

[Here are the answer for this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841672/unable-to-type-in-input-with-unity-webgl-background-div-in-react-js/46850020#46850020)